# Long running innodb query generate a big undo file in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a big query in php using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT not to put all the results into the php memory.
Because if I use MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT it will put all of the data into memory for all results, which takes multiple GB of ram, instead of getting row by row.
 It returns millions of rows and each row will generate an api request, so the query will be running for days.
In the mean  time, I have other mysql queries that update/insert the tables related to the first query, and I think it cause the undo log to grow without stopping.

I setup innodb_undo_tablespaces=2 and innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON
so the undo log is separated from ibdata1, but the undo files are still big until I kill the queries that have been running for days.

I executed "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;" before running the long running query, hoping that it would prevent undo file to grow, but it didn't.

The other queries that are updating/inserting have autocommit.

In 1-2 day, the undo file is already 40GB large.

The question : how to prevent this undo file to increase ? As I don't want to keep the previous version of the data while the query is running. It's not important if I get updated data instead of the data that was at the time of the query.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This appears to be related to server configuration, so it's a better fit on [the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com). I didn't down-vote, but don't take the votes too personally. People can be cranky.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I notice that downvotes often occur when there isn't a question in the post. And there isn't a question in your post.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a query which is being executed for more almost 2 days straight? Why? This is going to use up all your resources on the server.

Comment: i edited to add a question.
yes a query is executed for multiple days,  it's because i need to ask an api for millions of entries, so i did a mysql query to get the entries from the mysql database and then i query the api one by one. Doing millions of request to the api takes days

Comment: it doesn't use all resources on the server as mysql will wait after each row that php have finished processing that row

Comment: Let's study the query and discuss whether it can be made much smaller.

Comment: the query can't be made smaller

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your transaction isolation level, a given query will always establish a fixed snapshot, which requires the data to be preserved in the state it was when the query started.

In other words, READ-COMMITTED or READ-UNCOMMITTED allow subsequent queries in the same transaction to see updated data, but a single query will never see a changing data set. Thus concurrent updates to data will force old record versions to be copied to the undo log, and those record versions will be preserved there until your long-running query is finished.

READ-UNCOMMITTED doesn't help any more than READ-COMMITTED. In fact, I've never needed to use READ-UNCOMMITTED for any reason. Allowing "dirty reads" of unfinished transactions breaks rules of ACID databases, and leads to anomalies.

The only way to avoid long-lasting growth of your undo log is to finish your query.

The simplest way to achieve this is to use multiple short-running queries, each fetching a subset of the result. Finish each query in a timely way.

Another solution would be to run the whole query for the millions of rows of result, and store the result *somewhere* that isn't constrained by InnoDB transaction isolation.

- MyISAM table
- Message queue
- Plain file on disk
- Cache like Memcached or Redis
- PHP memory (but you said you aren't comfortable with this because of the size)